# Checkbox in Datagrid MVVM WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

The View ConfigRole has 2 columns, Name and IsEnabled(checkBox)with Button Edit for every row,

ConfigRole:

[image]

** If CheckBox is TRUE for a Row in ConfigRole View,when I click on Edit Button I get new View Button_Lists which has 2 columns Name_Button and IsEnabled(CheckBox)...and I modify TRUe or FALSe for every IsEnabled.

**My objectif is : When IsEnabled ConfigRole is FALSE, I want to get all the IsEnabled Button_Lists default to FALSE,

ButtonList:

[image]

this is my try code in Button_Lists Model:

```
 // get all of ButtonsList 
 public ObservableCollection<ButtonRoleMapClass> ButtonList
    {
        get { return _buttonList; }
        set
        {
            _buttonList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ButtonList");
        }
    }

    //viewRoleButton: the Name of selected row in ConfigRole
     public ButtonListViewModel(ViewRoleMapClass viewRoleButton)
    {               

        //If IsEnabled for row in ConfigRole is FALSE
        if (viewRoleButton.IsEnabled==false)
        {
            ObservableCollection<ButtonRoleMapClass> butsList = new ObservableCollection<ButtonRoleMapClass>();
            foreach (ButtonRoleMapClass button in _buttonList)
            {
                button.IsEnabled = false;
                butsList.Add(button);
            }
            _buttonList = butsList;                
        }
```

I want to get all CheckBox in Datagrid for View Button_Lists default is FALSE,

But with my code, I have this  Error:[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: what's the error ? can you give the code of the view as well ?

Comment: Use ButtonList = butsList direct. Then your PropertyChanged should work.

Comment: No, _buttonList is the value;so _buttonList = butsList; is correct

Comment: Do you set the value of _buttonList anywhere? If so its initial value is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you have initialized the `_buttonList` by adding an if statement that check whether `_buttonList` is `null`. If you get rid of the exception, you know that the `ObservableCollection` hasn't been initialized

You probably also want to set the **B**uttonList *property* to the new collection:

```
public ButtonListViewModel(ViewRoleMapClass viewRoleButton)
{
    //If IsEnabled for row in ConfigRole is FALSE
    if (viewRoleButton.IsEnabled == false)
    {
        ObservableCollection<ButtonRoleMapClass> butsList = new ObservableCollection<ButtonRoleMapClass>();
        if (_buttonList != null)
        {
            foreach (ButtonRoleMapClass button in _buttonList)
            {
                button.IsEnabled = false;
                butsList.Add(button);
            }
        }
        ButtonList = butsList;
    }
}
```

Comment: It works now,when I verify   if (_buttonList != null)
Thanks a lot :)